# Update document properties in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

What are the steps to UPDATE the properties in a document in MarkLogic? 
Can anyone please do the needful.

I have tried the below code:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace dls = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/dls" at "/MarkLogic/dls.xqy";
dls:document-set-properties(
  "/Test/A.pdf", 
  (<Product>1</Product>)
)
```

This throws an error stating the document is not managed. Please advice.

Answer (score 2):

The [DLS library](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/dls#chapter) is for a very particular use. To update properties, you can use one of these functions:

- [xdmp:document-add-properties()](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-add-properties)
- [xdmp:document-set-properties](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-set-properties)
- [xdmp:document-set-property()](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-set-property)
- [xdmp:document-remove-properties()](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-remove-properties)